# How can i make every <p> tag clickable on a pop-up by using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, popup

as you can see my code is working with sql. Every email name
 will be shown on a "pop up". And all of them will have separated p tag. What i am trying to make is when users click this p tag they must access another page. I am new to php and did something wrong . Some help would be great. Thanks.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Following">
  <?php
  $x=0;
  $arrayName = array();
  $sqls = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE member_email='$email'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqls);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayName[$x]  = $row["person_email"];

    $x=$x+1;
  } ?>
  <?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>
    <p id="pop" value="$arrayName[$k]" onclick="popFunc(this.value)"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>

  </div>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function popFunc($element){

$_SESSION['visiter']=$element; 
document.location.href = 'http://localhost/example/visiter.php';

}
```

Comment: changing page location hrefs based on a click is the job of an `<a>` element - and incidentally your loop will create identical id's for each.

Comment: paragraph tag dont have value attribute , you can achieve is by getting the innerText of the p tag by sending the tag id inside javascript function .or use a href to direct the page

Comment: `$_SESSION['visiter']=$element; ` will never work. By the time javascript runs in browser php no longer exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix Javascript and PHP in a function.
Here is a solution

```
<div id="dialog" title="Following">
  <?php
  $x=0;
  $arrayName = array();
  $sqls = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE member_email='$email'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqls);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayName[$x]  = $row["person_email"];

    $x=$x+1;
  } ?>
  <?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>
    <p id="pop" onclick="popFunc('<?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?>')"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>

  </div>
<?php } ?> 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<script>
function popFunc(element){
document.location.href = 'http://localhost/example/visiter.php?visiter='+element;
}
</script>
```

And your visiter.php:

Replace `$_SESSION['visiter']` with `$_GET['visiter']`

Comment: You have an error on `<p value>` tag, you are not doing `<?php echo $arrayName[$k]; ?>`

Comment: we don't need the value actually, but you're right :) Edited

Comment: It was an author error I didn't see on his question, sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

The onclick() in this line
`<p id="pop" value="$arrayName[$k]" onclick="popFunc(this.value)"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>`

it means call the function of javascript. And better you change `<p>` to be `<a>` tag. So the full script like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

function popFunc(name){
alert(name);
}

</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Following">
  <?php
  $x=0;
  $arrayName = array();
  $sqls = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE member_email='$email'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqls);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayName[$x]  = $row["person_email"];

    $x=$x+1;
  } ?>
  <?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>
    <a id="pop" href="#" onclick="popFunc(<?= $arrayName[$k] ?>)"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></a>

  </div>
```

Hope it can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not correct, you are mixing Javascript with PHP.

This `onclick="popFunc(this.value)"` will try to run JavaScript code, that is not defined in your code.

**PHP** is a **Server side** code, and **JavaScript** is a **Client side** code. I am not very knowledge at JavaScript, so I cant help you there, but you can search for **jQuery** and **JavaScript** tutorials.

**PHP** will run always before **HTML/JS/CSS** because is Server side. So, if you want to get data without changing page, you must use **AJAX**. This is not hard, but you require to know JavaScript.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm) is a good tutorial to help you.

---

## EDIT

I wrongly read the code on `p` tag. He is mixing HTML and PHP, but I didnt see that he wrongly called the `popUp` function. He done:

```
<p id="pop" value="$arrayName[$k]" onclick="popFunc(this.value)"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>
```

And what is correct

```
<p id="pop" onclick="<?php popFunc($arrayName[$k]); ?>"><?= $arrayName[$k]; ?><?= $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>
```

And his function:

```
function popFunc($element){

    echo "window.location = 'http://localhost/example/visiter.php?element=$element'";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property only exists on elements that take user input. You should use a `data-*` attribute to add arbitrary data to other types of elements. Or you could simply put the value directly into the `popfunc()` argument list. Or, since the value is also in the text of the paragraph, you can use `this.textContent`, which is what I've done in my answer.

You also should have the definition of `popfunc()` outside the loop, it doesn't need to be redefined for each item.

```
<?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>
    <p id="pop" onclick="popFunc(this.textContent)"><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>
<?php }
```

However, your `popFunc` function can't work as written. It's a Javascript function that runs on the client, it can't set PHP variables like `$_SESSION`. If you want to do something on the server when the user clicks, you need to use AJAX. Or you could pass it as a parameter when redirecting to the new location.

```
function popFunc(element) {
    document.location.href = 'http://localhost/example/visiter.php?visitor=' + encodeURIComponent(element);
}
```

Then `visitor.php` can assign to the session variable with:

```
$_SESSION['visitor'] = $_GET['visitor'];
```

Comment: I think he doesn't know that he is mixing PHP with JS.

Comment: He seems to be doing that correctly, except he forgot to use `<?php echo ... ?>` in one place.

Comment: Oh yes, I wrongly read that line of code, sorry, you are right.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that `popFunc()` tries to set a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Following">
   <?php
       $x=0;
       $arrayName = array();
       $sqls = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE member_email='$email'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqls);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $arrayName[$x]  = $row["person_email"];
           $x=$x+1;
   } ?>
   <?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>
       <p id="pop" onclick="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $arrayName[$k]; ?>', '_blank');">
       <?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p><?php } ?>
</div>
```